# Can't set tocdepth when including external PDF using pdfpages

Tags: table-of-contents, pdfpages

#### What I'm trying to do

I have a document with an appendix that consists of multiple chapters.

1. The first `\chapter` should not receive any special treatment.
2. For the second `\chapter` I'd like to exclude `\section` headings from the TOC. This can be achieved by placing

   ```
   \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
   ```

   in front of the `\chapter`.
3. The third `\chapter` should include all pages of an external PDF file. This can be achieved by adding

   ```
   \includepdf[pages=-]{external.pdf}
   ```

   to the chapter.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\part{Appendix}
\appendix

\chapter{First appendix}
\section{Section}

\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\chapter{Second appendix}
Don't list sections in TOC, please.

\section{Section}
Should not be listed in TOC.

\chapter{Third appendix}
Should include all pages of external PDF file.

\includepdf[pages=-]{external.pdf}
\end{document}
```

#### Problem

If I *only* set `tocdepth` (and omit the code that takes care of including `external.pdf`), the document compiles cleanly.

Similarly, if I *only* include `external.pdf` (and omit the code that changes `tocdepth`), the document also compiles cleanly.

However, when I try to compile the file as shown in the MWE above, I get the the following error message:

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                              {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...
l.23 \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
```

**Q:** How can I address all of the requirements stated above *and* get the document to compile cleanly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `pdfpages` loads `calc`, which makes `\setcounter` fragile.

Solution:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Case closed. Thanks a lot!